# Create extra combined html table from sql database with php

Tags: php, html, sql

Before marking this post double, read carefully. I have a `MySQL` base with 3 tables, `T1`, `T2` and `T3`. Their data are these:

T1:

```
name  val1  val2    
John    1    2    
Mary    1    2
```

T2:

```
name  val3  val4    
John    3    4    
Mark    1    2
```

T3:

```
name  val5  val6    
John    5    6    
Mark    3    4    
Mary    4    5
```

and I want to create the following combined html table:

```
name  val1  val2  val3  val4  val5  val6    
John   1      2    3      4    5      6    
Mary   1      2    -      -    4      5    
Mark   -      -    1      2    3      4
```

It seems very complicated to me. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TX.NAME,
(SELECT val1 FROM T1
    WHERE T1.NAME = TX.NAME) AS V1,
(SELECT val2 FROM T1
    WHERE T1.NAME = TX.NAME) AS V2,
(SELECT val3 FROM T2
    WHERE T2.NAME = TX.NAME) AS V3,
(SELECT val4 FROM T2
    WHERE T2.NAME = TX.NAME) AS V4,
(SELECT val5 FROM T3
    WHERE T3.NAME = TX.NAME) AS V5,
(SELECT val6 FROM T3
    WHERE T3.NAME = TX.NAME) AS V6
FROM (
SELECT NAME FROM T1
UNION
SELECT NAME FROM T2
UNION
SELECT NAME FROM T3) AS TX
```

We can do it with one sub-query per different column.

Comment: By executing your command I get: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN T2
ON T1.name = T2.name
' at line 3 "

Comment: There is no full outer join in mariadb, i will change my answer.

Comment: The new command returns: John | 1 | 2 |  |  |  | 
Mary | 1 | 2 |  |  |  | 
John | 3 | 4 |  |  |  |   
Mark | 1 | 2 |  |  |  | 
John | 5 | 6 |  |  |  | 
Mark | 3 | 4 |  |  |  | 
Mary | 4 | 5 |  |  |  |    there sould be 3 lines, not 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for your time! I do appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated.

If MySQL is your stronger language, write a query that joins the three tables with the desired values in the desired columns (into an array).

If PHP is your stronger language then write three queries that selects the values from each table (into distinct arrays). Then "join" those arrays into one array with the desired columns.

You want the result, in either case, to be an array with one "key" per user that has the 6 values.

You can iterate that result into an html table straightaway.

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select name, sum(val1) as val1, sum(val2) as val2,
       sum(val3) as val3, sum(val4) as val4,
       sum(val5) as val5, sum(val6) as val6
from ((select name, val1, val2, null as val3, null as val4, null as val5, null as val6 from t1
      ) union all
      (select name, null, null, val1, val2, null, null from t2
      )
      (select name, null, null, null, null val1, val2 from t3
      )
     ) t
group by name;
```

Or, if you know that `t3` has all the rows you want, use `left join`:

```
select t3.name, t1.val1, t1.val2,
       t2.val1 as val3, t2.val2 as val4,
       t2.val1 as val5, t2.val2 as val6
from t3 left join
     t1
     on t3.name = t1.name left join
     t2
     on t3.name = t2.name;
```

I don't recommend `full join`.  It is a bit tricky to create the correct query -- and easy to make a mistake that can filter out rows.

Comment: If I use all these 6 lines in the grey box and below it, then I get the error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'coalesce(sum(val4), 0) as val6 from ((select name, val1, val2, null as val3' at line 5 ".

Comment: @JohnStergiou . . . There was an typo (an extraneous line of code) that should not have been in the answer.

Comment: @JohnStergiou . . . There is no filtering in either query, so I don't see how non-empty tables could not return results .  Are you getting an error with the query.